# Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data thrown

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, fatal-error

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data thrown in /home/u801961841/public_html/inc/lib/base_facebook.php on line 814
```

This is the code I used:

```
    if ($result === false) {
      $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
        'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
        'error' => array(
        'message' => curl_error($ch),
        'type' => 'CurlException',
        ),
      ));
      curl_close($ch);
      throw $e;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
  }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to show the code where you are building/assigning the data you are trying to POST via curl.

Comment: I do not know what you mean code that ..

Comment: Well, the code where you call `curl_setopt(..., CURLOPT_POSTDATA, $whatever);` and the code where `$whatever` is created.

Comment: please download here to look real code n tell me,this problem..
[link](http://www.mediafire.com/?0q870kuy61dsoyy)

Comment: Ok, not really helpful. Please show the code where you are performing the call to the FB api (`$result = ...`).

Comment: i think you can download here [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?n8pmuy824jltypw)

Comment: Please get some basic knowledge of how to debug in PHP before you continue building apps on FB platform in PHP … here is not the place to teach absolute beginners the basics, there’s other places for that (tutorials etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The path to the image is not correct.
Correct it and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are trying a file upload to Facebook, such as a photo upload. Something that involves reading a file and building into the call.

If not, then amend the question. (Your link for the source doesn't work for me - so put the relevent bits in the question.)

If so, then this error is because PHP cannot read the file that you are trying to upload. Check the file exists, check your permissions for the file, and that PHP/Apache user has rights to read it. You can do this with file_exists() and is_readable() before you build the facebook call.

Comment: owh .. file_exists () & is_readable () can be changed where often? base facebook?

Comment: Use those two functions to check that the file you are trying to upload CAN be uploaded. Use then before you make the call to facebook, i.e. before you go $facebook->... You do not need to ammend facebook.php or base_facebook.php. (Assuming you are trying to upload a file)

Comment: As in where to put those functions? You can do them right after the <?php at the very top of the very first file to check the file is readable if you like. Or just before the facebook call. How about you give is a shot? Try it? You're going to come across a lot trickier problems to solve with facebook so you may as well learn how to debug. :)

Comment: I am still new in PHP. So? I still do not understand what you said ..
do I need to give any on you to solve this problem? script?

Comment: You have to read the manual and try some things. You know "echo" will output content. You can read the manual about what those two functions I gave you do? And you have a file that you're trying to upload? So how about "echo file_exists('YourFileName');" for starters. Then "echo is_readable('YourFileName');" and see what you get? Obviously change "YourFileName" for what the actual file is. Then read about permissions until you can read the file. You can show me a script - but you really need to work on debugging so please, give it a shot yourself.

Comment: "YourFileName"? i know echo.. whether the file that there needs to be replaced? example : echo file_exists('masterfile.php')?

Comment: That's the file that you're uttering to upload to Facebook? Post your code leading to to and including the Facebook calls (don't include Facebook.php or base_Facebook)

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading the file using $_FILE, You need to use the "realpath($_FILE)". But if you  are using local image file from your server, you need to use the dirname() to correctly point to the image.

dirname(dirname(dirname(**FILE**))).'/plugins/fun/images/'.$image_name;