# Couldn't post image into Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I am developing a Facebook application which gives results in an image.

I code it using PHP gd library and it is dynamic.

When you visit the page - "http://example.com/result.php?name=your name", it outputs an image file with your name given on the URL. 
My problem is in posting this image into Facebook user's photo stream. The user can see the output but when I try to post it, it displays

> Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file "http://mysite.orgfree.com/result.php?name=bestapp" thrown in /home/vhosts/powerofname.orgfree.com/base_facebook.php on line 977

Here is the code that I used to post

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
    'source' => '@'.'http://mysite.orgfree.com/result.php?name='.$name,
    'message' => 'Blah blah'
));
```

I would be grateful if anyone can spot my problem.

Comment: Check the file exists, check your permissions for the file, and that PHP/Apache user has rights to read it. You can do this with file_exists() and is_readable() before you build the facebook call.

Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062427/fatal-error-uncaught-curlexception-26-failed-creating-formpost-data-thrown

Answer (score 2):

If you are providing an HTTP URL for the image (instead of an actual upload), then you have to use parameter `url` instead of `source`:

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
    'url' => 'http://mysite.orgfree.com/result.php?name='.$name,
    'message' => 'Blah blah'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide path to image on filesystem, not on web. So you have to download image, save it to file, provide path to this file, upload and remove image from disk.

```
$tmpfile = tempnam(__DIR__,'fbu');
file_put_contents($tmpfile, 'http://powerofname.orgfree.com/result.php?name='.$name);
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
    'source' => '@'.$tmpfile,
    'message' => 'Blah blah'
));
unlink($tmpfile);
```

Comment: but I am hosting in free hosting company. How can I create temporary file on the Directory??

Comment: Usually it is done by creating folder with ftp and setting write permissions for it.